# Checked change event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to enable and disable textfields on checked change event but this event is not firing.
***Following is my radio button code***

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="submitter" runat="server" GroupName="rd2" OnCheckedChanged="submitter_CheckedChanged" Text="Submitter" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:RadioButton ID="following" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="Following" GroupName="rd2" OnCheckedChanged="following_CheckedChanged" />
```

***Following is my checked change event code***

```
protected void following_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (submitter.Checked == true)
        {
            contactName.Enabled = false;
            Contactmail.Enabled = false;
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('following event submitter check')</script>");
        }
       if (following.Checked == true)
        {
            contactName.Enabled = true;
            Contactmail.Enabled = true;
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('following event following check')</script>");
        }
    }

    protected void submitter_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (submitter.Checked == true)
        {
            contactName.Enabled = false;
            Contactmail.Enabled = false;
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('submitter event submitter check')</script>");
        }
        if (following.Checked == true)
        {
            contactName.Enabled = true;
            Contactmail.Enabled = true;
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('submitter event following check')</script>");
        }
```

Please tell me where is problem. thanks

Comment: Assign AutoPostBack="true" for radio button/s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `AutoPostBack="true"`

Postback means sending Data to server. It will execute server side events.
for more Details [Click Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/2f73dd/what-is-postback-in-Asp-Net/)

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="submitter" runat="server" GroupName="rd2" OnCheckedChanged="submitter_CheckedChanged" Text="Submitter" AutoPostBack="true" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:RadioButton ID="following" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="Following" GroupName="rd2" OnCheckedChanged="following_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks you it works. Kindly tell me what is purpose of it? I am new in asp so i don't know. thanks

Comment: @RamiFar See Updated Answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `AutoPostBack="true"`.

Change the aspx code to as below:

```
<asp:RadioButton AutoPostBack="true" ID="submitter" runat="server" GroupName="rd2" OnCheckedChanged="submitter_CheckedChanged" Text="Submitter" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:RadioButton AutoPostBack="true" ID="following" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="Following" GroupName="rd2" OnCheckedChanged="following_CheckedChanged" />
```